# Adding labels to first and last joint in polyline using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I am new to Leaflet, I am currently trying to add two labels, at the first and last joint of my GeoJSON polyline. I tried to open tooltips directly on map and adding markers with coordinates and a bounded tooltip but no luck.
When `refresh` function is called, polylines are added to map, but permanent tooltips bounded to the markers I add to map in the `onEachFeature` function don't appear. Even tooltips added by iterating the `labels` variable aren't shown.

Here is my messy code:

```
refresh(state, map) {
  console.log("refreshing");
  if(this.geoJSONLayer) {
    this.geoJSONLayer.clearLayers();
  }
  var labels = [];
  L.geoJSON(state.support_map).addTo(map);
  this.geoJSONLayer = L.geoJSON(state.document_map, {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
      layer.on('click', (e) => {
        e.target.editing.enable();
      });
      L.marker(feature.geometry.coordinates[0]).bindTooltip('HEY!', {
        permanent: true
      }).addTo(map);
      L.marker(feature.geometry.coordinates[feature.geometry.coordinates.length - 1]).bindTooltip('HEY!', {
        permanent: true
      }).addTo(map);
      labels.push({
        lat: feature.geometry.coordinates[0][0],
        lng: feature.geometry.coordinates[0][1]
      });
      labels.push({
        lat: feature.geometry.coordinates[feature.geometry.coordinates.length - 1][0],
        lng: feature.geometry.coordinates[feature.geometry.coordinates.length - 1][1]
      });
    }
  });
  this.geoJSONLayer.addTo(map);
  if(state.draw === 'polyline') {
    this.polylineDrawer = new L.Draw.Polyline(map, {});
    this.polylineDrawer.enable();
  } else {
    this.polylineDrawer.disable();
  }
  labels.forEach((label)=>{
    map.openTooltip('HEY!', label, { permanent: true });
  });
}
```

The `state` variable contains what to render on `map`, which is a reference to the Leaflet map. In the code there are both the two approach I tried: adding markers with tooltip and open tooltips right from map. I would simply like to show a label at the start of my polyline and one at the end of it.

What did I do wrong?

You can see the whole [code here](https://github.com/fpezzati/movona/blob/feature/create_geometries_using_leaflet_editable/scouter-web/src/index.js).

Comment: @TomazicM I update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tooltips and markers are shown, but at the wrong location. Zooming out enough you would see them. Reason for this is that Leaflet for the input to it's methods/functions expects `[lat, lng]` order, but GeoJSON coordinates are given in `[lng, lat]` order.

So what is needed is just to swap the GeoJSON coordinates when using them as input to Leaflet methods, for example:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  if (feature.geometry.type == 'LineString') {
    var firstCoord = feature.geometry.coordinates[0];
    var lastCoord = feature.geometry.coordinates[feature.geometry.coordinates.length - 1];
    map.openTooltip('First', [firstCoord[1], firstCoord[0]], {permanent: true});
    map.openTooltip('Last', [lastCoord[1], lastCoord[0]], {permanent: true});
  }
}
```